# Powershell Call Operator and Receive-Job

Tags: powershell

I observe strange behaviour:
Calling `& "ssh" user@host cmd` in a script works just fine. it connects to host and executes the cmd.
But if i want to parallellize it using jobs i observer that

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& "ssh" user@host cmd}
Receive-Job -Job $job -Wait
```

Fails with the Receive-Job statement. It seems like powershell tries to execute the job result. E.g. if you litterally run the commands, ssh will complain that it could not resolve hostname. Receive-Job now generates an Error

NotSpecified: (ssh: Could not ...)

This gets especially strange if the ssh connects fine and the cmd has some output. E.g. if cmd is a bash script starting with "set -x; set -e" i recieve an error

NotSpecified: (set -e ...)

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: Does it prompt for a password?

Comment: No, i use a key file